# How do I implement Socket.io Leaderboard using AWS Dynamo DB cost-effectively?

Tags: database, node.js, real-time, websockets, aws

Every time a user submits a score, Socket.IO causes all the users get their leaderboard updated. This causes every single user connected through Socket.IO to read from the Dynamo DB database (every time the a user submits a score). As a result, my database gets several reads/sec.

This costs me ALOT!

How do I reduce read requests/sec to DynamoDB significantly, so I don't end up loosing a lot of money?

Comment: I might not understand the question, but why aren't you pushing the score down to clients with socket.io? Don't get clients to read the data -- tell them what the data is. Is this an approach that might work?

Comment: Also, a caching layer might help out a lot.

Comment: DAX (https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/) might help.